# loop while array key exists php

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, key

i have an array from a form that has 'blocks' of info like

```
$array = array(id1 => 1
                title1 => this title
                id2 => 2
                title2 => this title 2)
```

i am trying to loop through the array like so

```
$num = 1;
$posid = "id" . $num;
while (array_key_exists($posid, $_POST)) {
    echo $posid . "<br>";
    $num++;
}
```

but i keep getting stuck in an infinite loop.  where am i going wrong?

Comment: $posid doesn't change in the loop

Comment: -1: You never changed `$posid`... Your `echo` should be making that clear.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I wouldn't downvote him for making a rookie mistake. It's a fair question from a new developer. +1

Comment: @Matthew: I downvoted him for not performing any basic debugging. There is no evidence of research effort, and the question will never help anyone else. It is "too localised" - a request for free personal help debugging some code. That's not what Stack Overflow is for. Stack Overflow is a site for interesting questions about programming languages and code. Thanks.

Comment: @Matthew: Upvoting this stuff encourages it. [Please don't](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).

Comment: why do most progrmaing pros have a stick up there rear ends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is that you don't redefine `$posid` in the loop. You should do this:

```
$num = 1;
$posid = "id" . $num;
while (array_key_exists($posid, $_POST)) {
    echo $posid . "<br>";
    $num++;
    $posid = "id" . $num;
}
```

I would however suggest a totally different approach.. Any time you find yourself POSTing variables like this:

```
id1
id2
id3
...
```

The chances are you would have been better suited to use array access notation in your input field.

```
<input name="id[]" ... />
```

This would allow for PHP to aggregate all values from fields with that name into an array in POST.

You could then do something like

```
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: super thanks guys you helped my alot @barmar your reply helped and i would have given you the tick so to speak but mike phrased a bit better is all you have both given me something to work on thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

You need to update `$posid` after incrementing `$num`:

```
$num = 1;
$posid = "id" . $num;
while (array_key_exists($posid, $_POST)) {
    echo $posid . "<br>";
    $num++;
    $posid = "id" . $num;
}
```

It would probably be better if you named your form fields with array notation, e.g. `<input name="id[]" ...>`. Then `$_POST['id']` would be an array, rather than separate elements.

Answer (score 0):

You're in an infinite loop because **if** it exists in the array, you're never **removing** it from the array and you're never **updating** the value of your interrogated variable.

Therefore, every time the `while` loop gets evaluated it will be `true` because it's the same condition being tested repeatedly.

Do you mean to remove $posid from the array? Do you mean to update it?

Comment: I think he means to do the `$posid` assignment inside the loop, so it gets the updated `$num`.

Comment: @Barmar Whatever he intends to do.... his infinite loop is because he's not changing the interrogated variable.